# AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed While Merging Audio files in IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetexportsession

i have using this code which is working perfectly fine on previous version of IOS 9. but on IOS 9 version it is always going AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed

```
AVAsset *avAsset1 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/firstPart.caf",docsDir]] options:nil];
AVAsset *avAsset2 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/New-Recording.caf",docsDir]] options:nil];

AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
[composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetTrack *assetTrack1;
AVAssetTrack *assetTrack2;

if ([avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count > 0) {
    assetTrack1 = [[avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    assetTrack2 = [[avAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
}

CMTime insertionPoint = kCMTimeZero;
[track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration) ofTrack:assetTrack1 atTime:insertionPoint error:nil];
insertionPoint = CMTimeAdd(insertionPoint, avAsset1.duration);
[track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset2.duration) ofTrack:assetTrack2 atTime:insertionPoint error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mergedFilePart1.caf",documentsDirectory]];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status) {

        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");

        [self mergeAudioPart2];

    } else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status) {
        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Export Session Status: %ld", (long)exportSession.status);
    }
}];
```

i searched all over internet but, i didn't find any solution any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code *should* work, but without seeing your input files it's hard to tell. However it can still be improved.

You've got an unused mutable track for some reason. You can delete it:

```
AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
// This track is unused. Delete it!
// [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
```

When the export fails (`AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status`) check `exportSession.error` for more information. `AVFoundation` error messages often leave much to be desired, but you could be lucky.

You're exporting an m4a file, but the file suffix is `.caf`. Change it to `.m4a` (`AVAssetExportSession` doesn't appear to support exporting to `AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat`).
Make sure to always remove the output URL before exporting, you've forgotten to do this:

```
NSURL *ouputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mergedFilePart1.m4a",documentsDirectory]];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:ouputURL error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
exportSession.outputURL = ouputURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
```

`insertTimeRange:ofTrack:error:` returns a success flag and an error! Consult them! They might point to a problem with your code!

```
NSError *error;
if (![track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration) ofTrack:assetTrack1 atTime:insertionPoint error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR 1: %@", error);
}
```

This condition is strange. You check the existence of audio tracks in one asset, then use the other as well:

```
if ([avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count > 0) {
    assetTrack1 = [[avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    assetTrack2 = [[avAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: I am also getting one issue, please look into this and advise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239586/error-domain-avfoundationerrordomain-code-11800-the-operation-could-not-be-com

Answer (score 0):

the issue was here : 
//    [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid]; this line was adding extra track. now this code is working perfect on IOS 9 as well.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/firstPart.caf",documentsDirectory];
NSString *path2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/New-Recording.caf",documentsDirectory];

AVAsset *avAsset1 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1] options:nil];
AVAsset *avAsset2 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2] options:nil];

AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
//    [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetTrack *assetTrack1;
AVAssetTrack *assetTrack2;

if ([avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count > 0) {
    assetTrack1 = [[avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    assetTrack2 = [[avAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSError *error;

CMTime insertionPoint = kCMTimeZero;

[track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration) ofTrack:assetTrack1 atTime:insertionPoint error:nil];
insertionPoint = CMTimeAdd(insertionPoint, avAsset1.duration);
[track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset2.duration) ofTrack:assetTrack2 atTime:insertionPoint error:nil];

NSURL *outPutUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mergedFilePart1.caf",documentsDirectory]];


AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

exportSession.outputURL = outPutUrl;

exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status) {

        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
        [self mergeAudioPart2];

    } else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status) {

        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)exportSession.status);
        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Export Session Status: %ld", (long)exportSession.status);
    }
}];
```